# I have multiple ngFor in angular project use trackBy:trackByFunction with single function or create multiple function?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

```
trackByFunction (index, items) {
   return item.id;
```

}

```
trackByABCtList(index, item) {
        return item.id; // or item.id
    }

trackByEmployeelist(index, item) {
    return item.id; // or item.id
}

trackByTags(index, item) {
    return item.id; // or item.id
}

trackByGroup(index, item) {
    return item.id; // or item.id
}

trackByEmployeesrange(index, item) {
    return item.id; // or item.id
}

trackByDepartment(index, item) {
    return item.id; // or item.id
}

trackByFeedbackQuestion(index, item) {
    return item.id; // or item.id
}
```

All Function same return type item.id,
**SO My Question is**, *I need to multiple trackByFunction or it's okay use only one.*

Comment: Have you tried both options? It's pretty simple to test yourself

Comment: It's ok to use the same function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ok to have one function. This functions is pure (e.g. no mutations) so it won't matter which `*ngFor` will be calling the function, so you can even move this function to some `utils.ts` file and name it something like `trackById` and use this function across your project.